# Vim: generate table of contents for plain text files (not Markdown)?

Tags: vim, tableofcontents

I'm aware of Vim plugins such as [vim-markdown-toc](https://github.com/mzlogin/vim-markdown-toc), etc. but those apply to markdown files.  Are there any approaches/suggestions for auto-generating a tables of contents in plain-text files (.txt, or no extension) in Vim?  For example, something like:

```
CONTENTS

  ∙ Executive Summary
  ∙ Technical Review
    ∙ Biomedical Natural Language Processing
  ∙ Preliminary Work
```

... where (for convenience) headers could adopt the markdown syntax:

```
# EXECUTIVE SUMMARY

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ...
...

# TECHNICAL REVIEW

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ...
...

##  BIOMEDICAL NATURAL LANGUAGE PROCESSING

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ...
...

# PROPOSED WORK

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ...
```

Comment: As plain text files have no syntax for headings this will be impossible in general. If you are using markdown syntax only for headings maybe it is sufficient to `:set  filetype=markdown` and use the plugins for markdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like that:

```
:g/^#* /t0
```

This will copy all this lines to the top. Unfortunaly in the wrong order, reverse it:

```
:0,4g/^/m0
```

(You may need to increase the numer 4 here, it is for your example). Then select the lines in visual line mode and replace `#` with tab or spaces.

```
:'<,'>s/#/  /g
```

Then do some formating. You could of course automate this further.

Comment: Not bad!  Here's what I tried (quick test of your method): select all text (`ggVG`); find those headings, paste to top of file: (`:'<,'>:g/^#.*$/t0`); visual select those lines and reverse sort (`'<,'>:g/^/m0`); visual select those lines (again) and remove the leading hashtags, space (`:'<,'>s^#\{0,} //g`). Nice!

Comment: Glad I could show you some stuff. What information are you still missing to solve your issue?